# create morph relation in Laravel with different foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to use morph relation in Laravel to access another model and also I didn't want use id as a foreign key to connect them, actually I want use uuid column on option table as foreign key in morph relation.
the table that I want to use morphrTo: (report table):

```
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('exam_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('optionable_uuid');
        $table->string('optionable_type');
        $table->integer('spend_time')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
```

and related morhMany table is: (option table)

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('uuid');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
```

and my models same as below
// ReportModel

```
// OptionModelpublic function optionable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

// OptionModel

```
public function report()
{
    return $this->morphMany(ExamReport::class,'optionable','optionable_type','optionable_uuid','uuid');
}
```

but output data in morph relation return null witch part is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I must change morhTo model as same as below

```
public function optionable()
{
    return $this->morphTo('optionable','optionable_type','optionable_uuid','uuid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add diffrent primayKey in relation

```
 public function report()
    {
    $this->primaryKey = "uuid";
    return $this->morphMany(ExamReport::class,'optionable');
    }
```